# meaning of 腰を落としている

Tags: phrases

その舗装された地面の上に腰を落としている。
what does 腰を落としている means in this context? does it really means that lose waist? or its like 身を落とす。 means be humble?

Answer (score 7):

In this context, it's just another way of saying "to sit". 腰を下ろす is a synonym.

In a different context, 腰を落とす can also mean this:

[image: 腰を落とす]
<sub>©pan (https://www.kamitokatachi.com/), [redistributed](https://www.kamitokatachi.com/entry/2015/02/21/204117) with modification under [CC BY-NC 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/4.0/)</sub>

Comment: What are they doing, is that a fighting stance or are they exercising/stretching?

Comment: It's lowering your upper body for fighting, defending, sneaking, etc. I used an image because I felt "crouch", "stoop" and "squat" might mean something a bit different, but perhaps "crouch" is the best word in English?

Comment: @naruto wikipedia uses [partial squat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squatting_position#Partial_squat)

Comment: @ratchetfreak Ah, yes, that's it. That's an interesting article :D